# What is the best way to transfer certain data to another json document?

Tags: javascript, json, electron

Explanation:

I want to make an Electron app [Javascript **not jQuary**] (or am in the process of doing so) and would like to add a function that puts one config into the "format" of another.

The big file from which I want to take the information I currently read in via "dialog.showOpenDialog" and can also access the json object.

**Now to the problem:**

The file I get via the dialog is 8000 lines long and contains individual information that I want to pack into a smaller document with about 3000 lines.
Important: Individual information have a different name e.g. I want "ABCD: 23" from document 1 in the other as EFG: 23.

**Now my two questions:**

1. how can I best provide the smaller file for editing?
2. how can I convert the individual information without going through each line separately?

bigconfig.json:

```
{
    "EXAMPLE_CATEGORY": {
        "setting1": 0,
        "setting2": 1,
        "setting3": 115,
        "setting4": 0,
    },
```

Smallerconfig.json

```
{
    "EXAMPLE_CATEGORY": {
        "setting7": 115,
        "setting8": 0,
    },
```

**Edit**: What I want to achieve is that I can create (and save) a modified file with the information I packed from the big file into the small one.

In the smaller one should be all 3000 felt

Would really appreciate help... yesterday I did a lot of research and used the search engine for several hours.

Thanks in advance

Comment: with these json objects, what is your expected resultant object, do you want a combined object with taking union/intrsection of properties? kindly explain more.

Comment: If the keys / values in your large JSON object cannot be used to convey the new key names in your smaller JSON object then you have no choice but to define a form of conversion table. EG: Iterate through the lines in your large JSON object and look for a matching 'old' key. If found, add the 'new' key and associated value to your smaller JSON object. There is no other was to compare and convert keys without iterating though each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way your `smallerConfig` object will know which **new** keys to use is if you define them beforehand. To do this, you must create an object that links the **old** key names to the **new** key names. These **links** would be best defined in one place. The code below holds these **links** in the  `conversionTable`.

To build the `smallerConfig` object, you must loop (using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)) through the `bigConfig` object one line at a time. Here you will check if the key in the `bigConfig` object matches a key in the `conversionTable` (using the [in operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)). If a matching key is found, then we will use the key’s value in the `conversionTable` as the **new** key in the `smallerConfig` object. Using the `bigConfig` value in the creation of the `smallerConfig` object is easy.

```js
let bigConfig = {
    'EXAMPLE_CATEGORY': {
        'setting1': 0,
        'setting2': 1,
        'setting3': 115,
        'setting4': 0
    }
};

let smallerConfig = {
    'EXAMPLE_CATEGORY': {}
};

let conversionTable = {
    'setting3': 'setting7',
    'setting4': 'setting8'
};

// Iterate through the bigConfig object
for (let bigKey in bigConfig.EXAMPLE_CATEGORY) {
    // Check for a matching key in the conversionTable
    if (bigKey in conversionTable) {
        smallerConfig.EXAMPLE_CATEGORY[conversionTable[bigKey]] = bigConfig.EXAMPLE_CATEGORY[bigKey];
    }
}

console.log(smallerConfig);
```

Output will be:

```js
{
    'EXAMPLE_CATEGORY': {
        'setting7': 115,
        'setting8': 0
    }
}
```

Finally:

- Use `JSON.parse()` to convert the file contents from a string to a Javascript object.
- Use `JSON.stringify()` to convert the Javascript object back to a string for writing to the new file.

Comment: All right, thanks that works perfectly.

Also, do you happen to have an idea how to put multiple tables in a for loop? (different categories)

Comment: @notFunnys Best to ask a new question with an example data object and what code you have come up with so far to generate your html tables.