# Multiple tables in a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, electron

Hello dear stackoverflow community,

I want to make an Electron app [Javascript not jQuary] (or am in the process of doing so) and would like to add a function that puts one config into the "format" of another.

The big file from which I want to take the information I currently read in via "dialog.showOpenDialog" and can also access the json object.

**Now to the problem:**

The file I get via the dialog is 8000 lines long and contains individual information that I want to pack into a smaller document with about 3000 lines. Important: Individual information have a different name e.g. **I want "ABCD: 23" from document 1 in the other as EFG: 23.**

I had already asked this question and also received a good answer from a user[[click here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73061526/17389880) which also works well, however I have now copied and pasted the function several times (as below in the example with the for function)

And this is of course not the fine English way... **is there a way to make this more compact?**

BigCFG.json:

```
"ANIMALS"{
        "DOG": {
            "DOG1": "0" ,
            "DOG2": "1" ,
            "BREED": {
               "breed": "1",
               "breed": "2",
            },
        },
        "CAT": {
            "CAT1": "0",
            "CAT2": "1" ,
            "BREED": {
               "breed": "1",
               "breed": "2",
            },
        },
}
```

**Tables:**

```
let dogTable = {
'dog1':'dog2',
'dog3': 'dog4'
}

let dogbreedTable = {
'breed1':'breed2',
'breed3': 'breed4'
}

let catTable = {
'cat1':'cat2',
'cat3': 'cat4'
}
 let catbreedTable = {
'breed1':'breed2',
'breed3': 'breed4'
}
```

**The for function which I would like to have more compact:** (I have the currently about 40 times in my project in a row to test)

```
for (let bigKey in BigCFG.ANIMALS.DOG) {
  if (bigKey in dogTable) {
  smallCFG.ANIMALS.DOG[dogTable[bigKey]] = BigCFG.ANIMALS.DOG[bigKey]
                            }
for (let bigKey in BigCFG.ANIMALS.DOG.BREED) {
  if (bigKey in dogbreedTable) {
  smallCFG.ANIMALS.DOG.BREED[dogbreedTable[bigKey]] = BigCFG.ANIMALS.DOG.BREED[bigKey]
                            }
for (let bigKey in BigCFG.CAT) {
  if (bigKey in catTable) {
  smallCFG.ANIMALS.CAT[catTable[bigKey]] = BigCFG.ANIMALS.CAT[bigKey]
                            }
for (let bigKey in BigCFG.ANIMALS.CAT.BREED) {
  if (bigKey in catbreedTable) {
  smallCFG.ANIMALS.CAT.BREED[catbreedTable[bigKey]] = BigCFG.ANIMALS.CAT.BREED[bigKey]
                            }
```

**Expected smallCFG.json:**

```
"ANIMALS": {
    "CAT": {
         "cat": "3",
         "cat": "4",
        "BREED": {
           "breed": "2",
           "breed": "3",
        },
    },
    "DOG": {
         "dog": "3",
         "dog": "4",
        "BREED": {
           "breed": "3",
           "breed": "4",
        },
    }
}
```

I would be very grateful for the help and of course appreciate your time

Comment: The syntax for your `tables` is incorrect. You are only showing keys in your question. You need to have key / value pairs for the object to be valid. EG: `let dogTable = {'dog1': 'Dog 1', 'dog2': 'Dog 2', 'dog3': 'Dog 3', 'dog4': 'Dog 4'}`. How do you receive the data into your tables`? Do you manually type it in or are they converted into JSON from files?

Comment: I have added the tables only as an example.

The json is fed into the app by the user via dialog and I want to convert it to a smaller one with the necessary data (like in the last question) only that I don't want to write the for function to make the table very often (otherwise the code gets really confusing).

Comment: Understood, but we can't help with an output function unless we have valid input data. As previously stated, the syntax of your input table(s) is wrong. IE: They are not Javascript objects or arrays. EG: Is it supposed to be an object `let dogTable = {'dog1': 'dog2', 'dog3': 'dog4'}` or an array `let dogTable = ['dog1', 'dog2', 'dog3', 'dog4']`? Note the location of the commas. Having all colons is invalid syntax.

Comment: I also agree with @midnight-coding, Please correct the input data so that we can help in building the final output as right now input variables are not valid.

Comment: Hey, first of all thank you for your answers. I have adjusted the post a little - hope now everything is correct

Comment: I'm finding it difficult to understand the correlation between your
 `BigCFG.json` and `smallCFG.json` strings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understood your problem and constraints. What I get by your other questions is you need to transform a json document for one structure to another, right? Have you tried [JSONata](https://jsonata.org/)? Maybe it matches your requirements.

PS.: I've tried add this as a comment, but I don't have reputation enough

Comment: No unfortunately not, but thank you anyway